# How to validate textboxes before saving

Tags: c#, textbox

I got this code and what I am looking for is to validate the text boxes before saving. Now if I fill the textboxes then I clear any of them it saves anyway. How could I possibly check if the are all filled before saving? I was trying to add handlers for textchanged events but I didn't work. Any suggestion will be appreciated, cheers.

```
    public partial class frmTrainer : Form
    {
        public frmTrainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // We initialize new event handlers for the subjects textboxes
            this.englishTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(englishTextBox_KeyPress);
            this.mathsTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(mathsTextBox_KeyPress);
            this.physicsTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(physicsTextBox_KeyPress);
        }

        // We create a public list for all the textbox controls in the form 
        public List textBoxes = new List();

        private void frmTrainer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'rCMDataSet.Students_Credentials' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.students_CredentialsTableAdapter.Fill(this.rCMDataSet.Students_Credentials);

            // We initialize the List of textboxes
            textBoxAdd();
        }

        // We create method stubs for the KeyPress event on the subjects textboxes
        // to allow them receive only numeric inputs
        private void englishTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Numeric input accepted only");
            }
        }

        private void mathsTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Numeric input accepted only");
            }            
        }

        private void physicsTextBox_KeyPress(object sendet, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Numeric input accepted only");
            }            
        }

        // We create a method to add each textbox to the List
        private void textBoxAdd()
        {
            textBoxes.Add(studentIDTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(first_NameTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(last_NameTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(usernameTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(passwordTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(englishTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(mathsTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(physicsTextBox);
            textBoxes.Add(trainerIDTextBox);
        }

        // We create a private method to validate the textboxes
        private void CheckTextBox()
        {
            foreach(TextBox txt in textBoxes)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please insert data correctly");
                }
            }
        }

        private void students_CredentialsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CheckTextBox();

            try
            { 
                //this.Validate();
                this.students_CredentialsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.rCMDataSet);
                MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // We disable the automatic validation when clicking Exit button
            this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;

            // We call the method to close the application
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // We disable the navigation buttons to prevent any skipping errors
            this.bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = false;
            this.bindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = false;
            this.bindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = false;
            this.bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, what do you mean with 'fill' or 'filled'? Sorry I didn't get what you want in your question.

Comment: Without changing your existing code too much, you could just return a boolean in `CheckTextBox`, indicating success or failure. If it detects any invalid data in the checkboxes, don't save anything in `students_CredentialsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click()`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: rfernades How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `students_CredentialsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click` event, while you do call the `CheckTextBox` method to "validate" your controls, you're essentially not doing anything about empty controls except to show a `MessageBox`. What you should do is to return a boolean on the validation method whenever an empty input is found:

```
    private bool CheckTextBox()
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        foreach(TextBox txt in textBoxes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
            {
                isValid = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert data correctly");
                break; //You only need one invalid input to prevent saving
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

And in your Click event, check for the return value of the method and exit the event if an invalid input is detected:

```
    private void students_CredentialsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!this.CheckTextBox()) return; //Stop executing code if there's invalid input

        try
        { 
            //this.Validate();
            this.students_CredentialsBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.rCMDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the String.Trim method on your text box text like:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in textBoxes)
        {
            //trim whitespaces from text at both ends and might be better to operate on a string

            String text = txt.ToString();
            text.Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert data correctly");
            }
        }
```